# I wish to know how I can prevent Prettier to format my js code in this strange form

Tags: javascript, file, format, prettier

I started to use Prettier inside my Microsoft Visual Studio Code (MVSC), but, when formatting a javascript file, I get some strange formatting.

For example, if I have this code:

```
    if ($("#epgprogramdescription" + channelListIndexOffset + ":nth-of-type(" + (programListIndexOffset + 1) + ")" ).length) {
        $("#epgprogramdescription" + channelListIndexOffset + ":nth-of-type(" + programListIndexOffset + ")").removeClass("epgtablerowselected");
        $("#epgprogramdescription" + channelListIndexOffset + ":nth-of-type(" + (programListIndexOffset + 1) + ")").addClass("epgtablerowselected");
    } else {
        programListIndexOffset--;
    }
```

It get it formatted as:

```
    if (
        $(
            "#epgprogramdescription" +
                channelListIndexOffset +
                ":nth-of-type(" +
                (programListIndexOffset + 1) +
                ")"
        ).length
    ) {
        $(
            "#epgprogramdescription" +
                channelListIndexOffset +
                ":nth-of-type(" +
                programListIndexOffset +
                ")"
        ).removeClass("epgtablerowselected");
        $(
            "#epgprogramdescription" +
                channelListIndexOffset +
                ":nth-of-type(" +
                (programListIndexOffset + 1) +
                ")"
        ).addClass("epgtablerowselected");
    } else {
        programListIndexOffset--;
    }
```

Any way to configure Prettier to maintain the original formatting?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `printWidth` option to a larger value in your prettier config? The default width is 80, which means prettier will attempt to wrap any lines longer than 80 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Prettier gonna always try to give line break your code if it **exceeds** your **print width** configuration.

You can change that by accessing vscode settings

1. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for "Prettier"
3. Look for configuration called "Prettier: Print Width"
4. And change it to suit your needs !

Give it bigger value if you want your code to stay in the same line. Prettier only break your code into new lines if it exceeds the given configuration

Comment: Changing the print width was the solution. I changed it to 180 and the code was formatted ok. But, it won't format and observe some how any wrap, if print width is narrow?